# asking question while installing with makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, installation, configure

I am trying to create an installation file for my library which has 3 parts, which part2 is depended to part 1 and part 3 is depended to part 2 and part 1.

It is possible that someone wants to install only one part, now the makefile should check is already installed the other required parts in the prefix location or not, and if not ask question if the user is sure to install that part?

for example to install part 2, the makefile should check whether part 1 is installed or not, and if it is not install ask "are you sure to install part 2 before part1?"

I should add that already in the make file there are 4 targets, `make part1`, `make part2`, `make part3` and `make all`. And there is no problem if someone install part3 without installing part2 or 1, but I wanna to verify that cuz it is possible that someone install a wrong part

how can I do that?
any Idea will be apreciated

Comment: Why ask the question? Do you really want to allow a user to install a part that cannot work?

Answer (score 3):

This is bad form. Have the person running make pass variables to it instead, containing the appropriate values.

Comment: Already in the make file there is 4 target, make part1, make part2, make part3 and make all. And there is no problem if someone install part3 without installing part2 or 1, but I wanna to verify that cuz it is possible that someone install a wrong part

Comment: Then make part3 dependent on part2, and then in turn part1. If the user has installed them outside of the default location then they will need to specify that location in order to find them.

Comment: Yes, surly, as it is mentioned in my question in the prefix location, so if they had installed somewhere and now they want to install in other place, the program must ask that question

Comment: Don't ask questions while running make.  Standard practice is to have a ./configure script that asks such questions.

Comment: but after executing ./configure, we decide which part should be install, for example, ./configure and then make part2. How we can use the configure.ac in this case?

Comment: `./configure` usually gives you options on what optional parts or features of the software to include, they usually have names starting with `--with-` - note that I hate configure scripts that are interactive, because they make it hard to script things

Answer (score 1):

As I see it, to install `part2` make has to install both `part1` and `part2`. This must be declared as dependency. Then `part3` depends on `part2`, which means `make part3` has to install all three parts: `part1` because `part2` depends on it, and `part2` because `part3` depends on `part3`.

This way, `all` target must depend on `part3`, and everything will be installed.

*`make` should not ask questions but resolve the dependencies automatically.* If user wants to install `part3`, then its dependencies must also be installed; otherwise it won't work, will it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes this is the goal and for instance it works like this, but how can I avoid reinstalling? I mean for installing part2 if the part1 is already installed, it should not install it again

Comment: @mahD It would depend on how to detect whether it's installed or not. There could be two possible approaches: 1. create additional target or declare dependencies so that make is able to figure it out on its own; 2. write something similar to a bash script in the `partX` targets. it will check for expected files, and perform copying only when they're not found.